# Is this a type casting error or are arguments not being passed to the method properly?

Tags: java, arrays, types

We are asked to do the following:

Receive the first names of your family members (between 3 to 6 members of your family), create an array of String.
Write a static method called generateNewName() as following:
It receives the array of String as a parameter.
It creates a new first name by using the 2nd character of each String from the array
Example: If you enter as first names Rocky, Ashley, Ocarina, Baron, Ernest, the resulting name should be oscar.
Display the names that were entered and newly generated name

This is what I have:

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Foothill {

```
static Scanner input;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    input = new Scanner (System.in);

    String[] getNames = new String[5];
    char Output;

    Output = generateNewName(getNames);

    System.out.println(Output);

    for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++){

        System.out.println("Enter 5 names: ");
        getNames[x] = input.nextLine();
    }
```

}

```
public static char generateNewName(String[] getNames)
{
    String newS = Arrays.toString(getNames);
    char result = '\0';

    for(int j = 0; j < getNames.length; j++){

    result = (char) (result + newS.charAt(1));
    }

    return result;
}
```

}

It is properly taking the input, however it seems to not be executing the generatNewName method. Am I doing something wrong with the types of methods i'm using? Should generateNewName return a string-type? If so, how do I get the second letter of all input strings and concatenate them? Thanks,

Comment: One thing, receiving the names as command line arguments means the names will be in the args parameter of the main method

Comment: Right I just edited that -- CL in not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your generateNewName() method should be returning a String, not a char.

Then you would have to change that

```
char result = '\0';
```

with

```
String result = "";
```

and then you start appending (using +) the letters to the String.

You can also read about StringBuilder, which would make the code more efficient.

Also, `String newS = Arrays.toString(getNames);` that line doesn't make much sense. You want to be looping through the names you have, not through all the letters of your name.

I would rewrite that loop to something like:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < names.length ; i++) {
  result += names[i].charAt(1);
}
```

or, using a for-each loop

```
for (String name : names) {
  result += name.charAt(1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks... that fixed the problem of the error, but i'm only getting an output of the first input's second letter repeated 5 times instead of the 2nd character of all 5 strings with this:

result = (String) (result + newS.charAt(2));

Answer (score 1):

`"Enter 5 names:"` is misleading. Consider `"Enter name " + (x + 1) + " (of " + 5 + "):"` or something similar.

But to answer your question: You are running `generateNewName` before you get any names! It's being executed for an array of only null elements!

Change this:

```
     Output = generateNewName(getNames);
     System.out.println(Output);
     for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++){
         System.out.println("Enter 5 names: ");
         getNames[x] = input.nextLine();
     }
```

to this

```
     for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++){
         System.out.println("Enter 5 names: ");
         getNames[x] = input.nextLine();
     }
     Output = generateNewName(getNames);
     System.out.println(Output);
```

:)

Also consider renaming your variables to (a) follow naming conventions such as variable names should be lowercase, and (b) to be more indicative of what they hold and what they are (string, char, array, etc.). Such as `names` or `nameArray` instead of `getNames` and `newName` or `outputName` instead of `Output`.

Finally, and as stated by others, you're using and returning a char in the `generateNewName`, and obviously a name is a string, not a char.

Answer (score 0):

- generateNewName should return a String, not a char. A char is a single character, like the letter A.
- You can't generate the new name before asking for the old names, right? Within a method, unless you say otherwise (e.g. with a loop), code runs from top to bottom, like a list of instructions.